# Before Validation loop through self attributes for modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord

I have created a simple before_validation:

```
  before_validation :strip_tabs

  def strip_tabs

  end
```

In my class I want to loop through all my attributes and remove tabs from each value. Most posts I found on SO are people who want to set 1 attribute. But I want to edit all my values.

**Question:**
How can I loop all self attributes of a model and edit them.

**Friend suggested this, but content_column_names does not exist:**

```
self.content_column_names.each {|n| self[n] = self[n].squish}
```

**UPDATE 1: More code:**

```
class PersonalInfo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks
  extend ActiveModel::Translation
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  include Sappable
  require 'ext/string'

  attr_accessor \
    :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name,:birthdate,:sex,
    :telephone,:street,:house_number,:city,:postal_code,:country,
    :e_mail, :nationality, :salutation, :com_lang

  validates :e_mail, :email => {:strict_mode => true}
  validate :validate_telephone_number
  validate :age_is_min_17?
    before_validation :strip_tabs

    def strip_tabs
      binding.remote_pry
    end

  def age_is_min_17?
    birthdate_visible =  PersonalField.not_hidden.find_by_name "BIRTHDATE"
    if birthdate_visible && birthdate && birthdate > (Date.current - 17.years)
      @errors.add(:birthdate, I18n.t("apply.errors.birthdate"))
    end
  end

  def validate_telephone_number
    telephone_visible = PersonalField.not_hidden.find_by_name "TELEPHONE"
    telephone_current = telephone.dup

    if telephone_visible &&  telephone_current && !telephone_current.empty?
      if telephone_current[0] == '+' || telephone_current[0] == '0'
        telephone_current[0]  = ''
        @errors.add(:telephone,  I18n.t("apply.errors.telephone")) if !telephone_current.is_number?
      else
        @errors.add(:telephone,  I18n.t("apply.errors.telephone"))
      end
    end
  end

  def initialize(hash)
    simple_attributes = [:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name,:birthdate,:sex,
                         :telephone,:street,:house_number,:city,:postal_code,:country,
                         :e_mail, :nationality, :salutation, :com_lang]
    simple_attributes.each do |attr|
      set_attr_from_json(attr, hash)
    end

    set_attr_from_json(:birthdate, hash) {|date| Date.parse(date) rescue nil}
  end
end
```

**Update 2: Rails Version:**
I'm using Rails '3.2.17'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as following:

```
before_validation :strip_tabs

def strip_tabs
  self.attributes.map do |column, value| 
    self[column] = value.squish.presence
  end
end
```

But I think that `.squish` will not work on `created_at, updated_at, id`, ... Because they are not String!

```
def strip_tabs
  self.attributes.map do |column, value|
    self[column] = value.kind_of?(String) ? value.squish.presence : value
  end
end
```

---

Since **your class is not a Rails model** (ActiveRecord::Base), you can do as following:

```
def strip_tabs
  self.instance_variables.map do |attr|
    value = self.instance_variable_get(attr)
    value = value.squish if value.kind_of?(String)
    self.instance_variable_set(attr, value)
  end
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #<PersonalInfo:0x007fcbd8295800>
from (pry):2:in `strip_tabs' For some strange reason self.attributes does not work. I'm testing this via pry.

Comment: This is because your object is not a model from `ActiveRecord::Base`, but a simple class.

Comment: What do you suggest on doing to get it working for this class?

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, I will edit the topic further since this is not a model.

Comment: Are you not at risk of getting / setting unintended instance variables this way (such as any introduced by modules, etc.)? I'm always wary of bulk actions where you don't check what you're changing (hence why I suggest using a whitelist).

Comment: `self.instance_variables` only returns the variables that were set, i.e. `Car.new(color: 'red').instance_variables` returns `[:@color]`, but  `Car.new(color: 'red', name: 'Audi').instance_variables` returns `[:@color, :@name]`. So I guess it is sufficient - in my opinion - to leave it like this.
I

Comment: @MrYoshiji please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826226/instance-variables-in-class-not-being-saved

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def strip_tabs
    self.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
        modified_value = ... # calculate your modified value here
        self.write_attribute attr_name, modified_value
    end
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #<PersonalInfo:0x007fcbd8295800>
from (pry):2:in `strip_tabs' I will post more code in a sec.  I'm testing this via pry

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using Rails '3.2.17'

Comment: You need to extend ActiveRecord::Base in you model definition

Comment: thanks for your answer, I appreciate every piece of wisdom you give.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not an ActiveRecord model you won't have `attributes` or `column_names`, but you already have an array of your attribute names in your `initialize` function. I would suggest making that into a constant so you can access it throughout the model:

```
class PersonalInfo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks
  extend ActiveModel::Translation
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  include Sappable
  require 'ext/string'

  SIMPLE_ATTRIBUTES = [:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name,:birthdate,:sex,
                     :telephone,:street,:house_number,:city,:postal_code,:country,
                     :e_mail, :nationality, :salutation, :com_lang]

  attr_accessor *SIMPLE_ATTRIBUTES

  before_validation :strip_tabs

  def strip_tabs
    SIMPLE_ATTRIBUTES.each{ |attr| self[attr] = self[attr].squish }
  end

  ...

  def initialize(hash)
    SIMPLE_ATTRIBUTES.each do |attr|
      set_attr_from_json(attr, hash)
    end

    set_attr_from_json(:birthdate, hash) {|date| Date.parse(date) rescue nil}
  end
end
```

Comment: That seems heavy to set, handle and "copy" to other classes.

Comment: @DaveMongoose, thanks for your help I will wait for MrYoshiji with the explanation about " set, handle and "copy" to other classes"