# Instance Variables in class not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, instance-variables

I'm filtering all my instance values of my PersonalInfo class via before_validation like this:

```
  before_validation :strip_tabs

  def strip_tabs
    self.instance_variables.map do |attr|
      value = self.instance_variable_get(attr)
      if value.present? && value.kind_of?(String)
        encoding_options = {
          :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
          :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
          :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
          :universal_newline => true       # Always break lines with \n
        }
        value = value.encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options)
        value = value.squish 
        value = value.gsub("/t","") 
        self.instance_variable_set(attr, value)
      end
    end  
  end
```

This code was discussed here:

[Before Validation loop through self attributes for modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809794/before-validation-loop-through-self-attributes-for-modification/23810376?noredirect=1#23810376)

The strip_tabs works it transforms this:
"\t•\tzef"
Into this:
"zef"

In my test case I fill in last_name with the bad value ("\t•\tzef") and when I set a breakpoint here :

```
  def strip_tabs
    self.instance_variables.map do |attr|
      value = self.instance_variable_get(attr)
      if value.present? && value.kind_of?(String)
        encoding_options = {
          :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
          :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
          :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
          :universal_newline => true       # Always break lines with \n
        }
        value = value.encode(Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options)
        value = value.squish 
        value = value.gsub("/t","") 
        self.instance_variable_set(attr, value)
      end
    end  
binding.remote_pry
  end
```

The result is as expected correct:

[image]

**Now the important part that is not working:**

The code is started because I do this:

```
info = PersonalInfo.new(params["personal_info"])
```

When it's completed info.last_name is still the bad value:
[image]

**Problem:**
Why are the instance_variables not being saved?

**More info:**
- 'rails', '3.2.17'
- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-darwin13.0.2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to call

```
info.valid?
```

in order to trigger the validation hook if you are not saving `info` directly (which will trigger it implicitly).